# how to parse nagios status.dat ?

Tags: php, json

what im trying to achieve is to parse the nagios status.dat file using the statusJson.php script and then get some especific values.
So far , I generated the json file , converted to array or object using the json_decode function and print the result. there is where I realized that there are a lot of info missing in the resulting array.
The array deep is not more than 3 or 4. What i can see also is than all the sub-arrays with numeric keys are missing.
Dont know what to do , the resulting json was ok on many json online validators.
Regards.

Comment: Maybe you have some duplicated keys..

Comment: Sorry, but there is nothing we can say here without the actual JSON data.

Comment: To piggyback off of @arkascha's comment, there are a number of things that could be wrong. 

For instance, with 30k lines, it's certainly possible you went past the default maximum depth value of 512. There could also be escaping issues, conserved character issues, etc.

It may be useful to provide the summary of the before and after diff. 

Any further info could only help.

Comment: I just _love_ that expression @clarkatron uses: "conserved character issues"... Wonder how those taste...